# In `dmesg | head`, (how) is dmesg being killed after 10 lines of output?

Tags: pipe, signals

If I run these commands:

```
dmesg | head -n 10
```

I presume the OS sends back some kind of signal to `dmesg` once `head` has read 10 lines. How does this work? What does `head` tell the kernel?

This is different from a program dying since this is a normal, 'clean' stop.

Comment: @muru: No, it's not a duplicated. That question about *what*, here is *how* and whether `dmesg` was killed after 10 lines.

Comment: @cuonglm *what makes something do x* is not necessarily equal to just *what*.

Comment: @muru: Yes, but reading that question, you only got some information about *how*, which was not the main purpose of this question.

Comment: How do you know it's a normal, clean stop?

Comment: `dmesg` receives EPIPE, just as described in the duplicate answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It depends on the OS buffers and the timing between the 10th and 11th writes of `dmesg`.

After `head` writes 10 lines, it terminates and `dmesg` will receive [SIGPIPE signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html#tag_13_42_03) if it continues writing to the pipe.

Depending on your OS buffer, `dmesg` will often write more than 10 lines before `head` consumes them.

To see that `head` had consumed more than 10 lines, you can use:

```
strace -f sh -c 'dmesg | head -n 10'
```

(Look at the `head` process, count on number of `read` system calls.)

To see how the writing speed effect:

```
strace -f sh -c "perl -le '$|++;print 1 while 1' | head -n 10"
```

Comment: Technically, `head` terminates after it *outputs* 10 lines; it may consume more than 10 lines of input before doing so.

Comment: @chepner: Yes, it's my typo, fixed.

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at the [POSIX specification for the `write()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html):

> The `write()` function shall fail if:
>
> … An attempt is made to write to a pipe or FIFO that is not open for reading by any process, or that only has one end open. A SIGPIPE signal shall also be sent to the thread.

So the sequence of events is:

1. The `head` process exits. This causes all its open file descriptors to be closed, including its standard input, which is one end of the pipe.
2. The `dmesg` process calls `write()` on its standard output, which is the other end of the pipe.
3. This causes a SIGPIPE to be delivered to the `dmesg` process.
4. `dmesg` has no special handling of SIGPIPE, so the default action is applied, which is to terminate the process.

You can experiment with this by changing the action for the SIGPIPE signal. For example, this pipeline terminates after printing one line:

```
$ yes | head -1
y
$
```

but if you ignore SIGPIPE, then it doesn't terminate:

```
$ trap '' PIPE
$ yes | head -1
y
```

At this point the `yes` process is still trying to write to the pipe but the writes are failing with EPIPE.

Answer (score 2):

`head` closes *stdin* after printing 10 lines. Then `dmesg` detects that the *stdout* is closed and exits.

To be more precise, `dmesg` will receive the `EPIPE` error from the `write` call to *stdout*.

From the *dmesg.c* source code here: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/v2.27.1/sys-utils/dmesg.c#L654-L659

```c
rc = fwrite(p, 1, len, out) != len;
if (rc != 0) {
    if (errno != EPIPE)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, _("write failed"));
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Highly unlikely `dmesg` will receive `EPIPE`. It's more likely `dmesg` will receive a `SIGPIPE`, and terminate.

Comment: You are right, `dmesg` will receive `SIGPIPE` and will exit with an error (it does not trap that signal).